# Entity Framework - Remove attributes from entities before the Add-Migration command will executed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have entities which have the same properties than an other entity, but with different validation attributes, like:

```
public class Person
{
       [Key]
       public Guid Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Firstname { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

And without the required attribute:

```
public class Person2
{
       [Key]
       public Guid Id { get; set; }

       public string Firstname { get; set; }

       public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

My strategy was to write the following code:

```
[EntityWithoutRequiredAttribute]
public class Person2 : Person
{
}
```

The problem is, that an entity framework migration generates a "nullable: false" expression:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Person2",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Firstname = c.String(nullable: false),  // should be nullable
                    Lastname = c.String(nullable: false),   // should be nullable
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Is it possible to remove all Required attributes from entities which have the custom attribute "EntityWithoutRequiredAttribute"? Is it possible to write an injector, which runs before the Add-Migration command?

Thanks!!!

Comment: No you can't. You must look about ViewModel.

Comment: just for try, you can change the code of the migration by hand, and make columns nullable by changing the value from `false` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

This would NOT be the BEST solution for your problem, but it could be an work around, or you can used as last solution.

you can change the migration manually as the following

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.Person2",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Firstname = c.String(nullable: true),  
                Lastname = c.String(nullable: true),   
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```